# Upload file to openshift pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have license key and I need it to upload to openshift pod, how? It cannot be uploaded to some random server, then to pod. Somehow I need to transfer from my local pc to linux terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `oc rsync` command to copy files. Refer [Copying Files to or from a Container](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/copy_files_to_container.html#copying-basic-usage)
.

For example, if the license key file is saved in `/path/to/license_dir`, the directory is sync with pod `target directory`.

```
oc rsync /path/to/license_dir your_pod_name:/tmp/license_dir
```

Comment: Just be aware that pods are ephemeral and can go away. If where you are putting the file is not in a persistent volume, you would need to do this every time the pod was killed due to re-deployment etc. Should instead perhaps look at a config map and mount that in as a file into the container.